# FFmpeg ogg - Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, ogg

I am trying to change the framerate of a Video of mine. Below there is the example Input and the Output. I Built ffmpeg myself and I'm pretty sure I miss the right decoder/demuxer but I have no Idea what I need. I thought --enable-libtheora would be enough to enable, muxers, demuxers, encoder and decoder, but apperently there is somehting missing. Does anybody have an idea about this?

I have inserted *path-to-ffmpeg* to make this shorter, the Path itself is okay, so no worries about that.

```
   *path-to-ffmpeg*\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -i Video.ogg -filter "minterpolate='fps=60'" out.ogg
ffmpeg version 3.3.git Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
  configuration: --disable-encoders --disable-decoder=hevc --disable-decoder=raw
video --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=flac --disable-decoder=ffwavesynth
 --disable-decoder=libcelt --disable-decoder=libgsm --disable-decoder=libilbc --
disable-decoder=libopus --disable-decoder=dvbsub --disable-decoder=dvdsub --disa
ble-hwaccels --disable-parsers --disable-bsfs --disable-protocols --disable-inde
vs --disable-outdevs --disable-devices --disable-filters --disable-muxers --disa
ble-demuxers --enable-muxer=ogg --enable-zlib --enable-libtheora --enable-libvor
bis --enable-shared --enable-encoder=libtheora --enable-encoder=libvorbis --enab
le-demuxer=image2 --enable-filter=framerate --enable-protocol=file --enable-filt
er=minterpolate --enable-filter=scale
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 85.100 /  6. 85.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
Video.ogg: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have `--disable-demuxers` but no `--enable-demuxer=ogg` after that. Depending on what the Oggs contain, your build may still be crippled.

Comment: Okay I feel kinda stupid now, but unfortunatly it doesn't work. I tried building it without disabling anything and with --enable-decoder-libvorbis and --enable-decoder-theora, I'm kinda confused because it's --enable-decoder-theora and not libtheora, but with libtheora I get a warning that it doesn't know the command. 
I treid:

./configure --enable-zlib --enable-libtheora --enable-muxer=ogg --enable-demuxer=ogg --enable-libvorbis --enable-encoder=libvorbis --enable-encoder=libtheora --enable-decoder=theora --enable-decoder=libvorbis

Comment: Use a static build from elsewhere and check if the file's valid.

Comment: It works with a prebuild, so the File should be okay. The File is also made with my ffmpeg build, from some Images, so the encoder seems to work fine.

Comment: Then run command with `-v 48`. A detailed log will be output.

Comment: That didn't give me much Information, but I tried it again with my previous Configure line and added the demuxers and muxers again and now it is working. I have no idea why it didn't work and now it does, but thanks for the help :)